# How to inject nested classes using Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am working on Android application. I am using Dagger2 for dependency injection. I am able to use this library but I don't know how to inject nested classes.

```
        public class Parent {

            @Inject
            public Parent()
           {}

            public String getParent() {

                return "fifth";
            }

            class ParentSubClass{

             @Inject
             public ParentSubClass(){
             }

                public String getParentSubClass(){
                    return "subfifth";
                }

            }
    }


  class SomeTest{

  @Inject
  Parent.ParentSubClass subclass;


}
```

I know injecting parent class but how to create object for parentsubclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Inject` constructors are not supported on inner classes as Dagger tells us in the logcat:

> error: @Inject constructors are invalid on inner classes public ParentSubClass()

If you'd like to provide your inner class, you should provide it using a `@Provides` method:

```
@Provides
internal fun provideSubclass() : ParentSubClass {
    return Parent().ParentSubClass()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested class in the example has access to all of its parent properties, so you can inject all dependencies you need in the parent and later use those in the subclass.

Comment: You misunderstood the question,I want to access nested class properties in other class

Comment: Please try to improve your example so that maybe I understand your question better.

Comment: I added some test class there i need to access nested class of some other class